# Python 3.5.1 - ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, dictionary, int

What my program does is
- Take a sentence
- Make a dictionary and puts it in an external txt file
- Make a list of numbers which indicates what words are in what positions
- Recreate the original sentence using the numbers and the dictionary and puts it in an external txt file
However, I get this error message when recreating the sentence:

```
line 22, in <module>
newoutput = (wordDictionary[int(numbers)]) + " "
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

and here is my code

```
sentence = input("What is your sentence? ")
splitWords = sentence.split()
wordPositions = ""
wordDictionary = {}

for positions, words in enumerate(splitWords):
    if words not in wordDictionary:
        wordDictionary[words] = positions+1
    wordPositions = wordPositions + str(wordDictionary[words]) + " "
fileName = input("What would you like to call your dictionary .txt file? ")
file = open (fileName + ".txt", "w")
for words in wordDictionary:
    output = words + "\t" + str(wordDictionary[words]) + "\n"
    file.write(output)
file.close()

numberList = wordPositions.split(" ")
wordDictionary = {y:x for x,y in wordDictionary.items()}
fileName2 = input("What would you like to call your sentance .txt file? ")
file = open(fileName2 + ".txt", "w")
for numbers in numberList:
    newoutput = (wordDictionary[int(numbers)]) + " "
    file.write(newoutput)
file.close()
```

How can I fix this error message?
Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have an empty string in `numberList`. The reason is the splitting of the text.

See the following example:

```
>>> 'xx  yy'.split()
['xx', 'yy']
>>> 'xx  yy'.split(' ')
['xx', '', 'yy']
```

If you use a delimiter you will always get a result, even if you split an empty string.

```
>>> ''.split(' ')
['']
```

To cite the documentation for [`split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split).

> If sep is not specified or is None, a different splitting algorithm is
>   applied: runs of consecutive whitespace are regarded as a single
>   separator, and the result will contain no empty strings at the start
>   or end if the string has leading or trailing whitespace. Consequently,
>   splitting an empty string or a string consisting of just whitespace
>   with a None separator returns [].

So at the moment you use `split(" ")`, but you should use `split()` without a parameter.

Comment: Thank you. This is perfect :)

Answer (score 0):

You are passing an empty String to the int() method.

It is saying that it doesn't know how to parse an empty string.
Echo printing and checking what your program is giving to the method would help you out the most for this.

Numbers in this case is an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

As designated by your traceback, you are passing in an empty string (''), and trying to make it an integer. You could either test for empty values before

```
newoutput = (wordDictionary[int(numbers)]) + " "
```

Or wrap the statement after it in a try/catch.

However, the best solution would probably be to prevent adding empty strings to your numbersList list before it is evaluated.